# Python random generator not so random?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is the python random generator considered "good"? As in, does it simulate randomness very well? I made a small program which simulates a person starting at (0, 0) and taking a random step either east, west, north and south. As you run simulations with larger and larger number of steps, you would expect the final position of the person to be closer and closer to the origin. However, as I increased the number of steps in my simulation, the final position was getting farther and farther away from the origin. The program I used is here:

```
import random

def walk():
    north = 0
    east = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        direction = random.randint(0, 100)
    if direction <= 25:
        north = north + 1
    elif direction > 25 and direction <= 50:
        north = north - 1
    elif direction > 50 and direction <= 75:
        east = east + 1
    else:
        east = east - 1
return north, east



def main():
    for i in range(500):
        north, east = walk()
        print("NE : ", north, east)


main()
```

Comment: The generator is fine for this purpose.  But you misunderstand the theory of "random walks" - work on that first ;-)  Note too that your code is biased:  e.g., there are 26 (not 25) values for which `direction <= 25` is true.

Comment: BTW; since you only have four outcomes of interest, simplify life and use `randrange(4)` instead.  Then you'll get one of {0, 1, 2, 3} with equal probability.

Comment: @TimPeters Yeah thanks, and I get it now it shouldn't get closer and closer to 0,0 like i tought :P

Comment: How _does_ one measure randomness, anyway? :)

Comment: @bcdan There are numerous ways for testing speudo-random numbers such as those generated by software. For example the [ent](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) program uses five different tests. Which tests are better depends on what you are looking for. People interested in random numbers for cryptography have much more stringent demands than those who just want to choose between four directions.

Comment: Python itself cannot generate really random numbers. Only *pseudo-random* numbers. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html) also has some background information about the pseudo-random number generator that Python uses, the Mersenne Twister.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As you run simulations with larger and larger number of steps, you would expect the final position of the person to be closer and closer to the origin.

This simply is not true. Imagine you start at (0,0). You take one step east, taking you to (1,0). Now, in order to get closer to the origin, you need to take a step west. Taking a step in any other direction will take you further from the origin. So, you have a 1/4 chance of going closer to the origin and a 3/4 chance of going further away from the origin. This is true no matter where you are; more often than not, a step will take you further from the origin. Thus, your simulation is behaving as expected; the longer you go, the further from the origin you get.

---

To see why this is true; consider a one-dimensional walk, where you can step left or right. If you take ten steps, the expected value is 50:50 left and right; 5 left and 5 right, taking you back to the origin. Of course, you might end up with 60:40 or 70:30, leaving you one or two steps away from the origin. It is a small sample size, after all. If you take 1000 steps, you might end up with something like 520 left to 480 right, pretty close to that 50:50 ratio. If you take 10000 steps, you'll be even closer to the 50:50 ratio, perhaps with something like 5050:4950.

However, there is something very important to note; as your sample size gets larger, the *proportion* of left to right steps is closer to 50:50, but the absolute *difference* in number between left and right steps gets *larger*. In that last case, you have a 50.5:49.5 ratio, but you're *fifty* steps away from the origin, compared to your one step away from the origin in the case where you have a 60:40 ratio with ten steps.

Comment: @JohnPirie Actually I think the poster is right, she's not saying that a bigger test won't get closer to the expected result, she's saying the expected result was false, which now makes sense

Comment: @Anonymous it is true, the expected distance from the origin for a random walk is greater than zero: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103142/expected-value-of-random-walk.

Comment: @CactusWoman That post doesn't necessarily explain why that is true though. Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly? Assuming no bias, shouldn't each direction theoretically have an equal chance of getting selected, meaning all of them would be cancelled out (a.k.a. nN - nS and nW - nE = (0,0))?

Comment: @Anonymous I updated my answer with some extra detail

Answer (score 2):

It's not python, it's this line:

```
        direction = random.randint(0, 100)
```

The above will generate a value 0 <= N <= 100, which is 101 possible values.  You have introduced bias into your generator, and given the bias, with larger numbers you will in fact stray further and further from the origin.

With an unbiased generator, your mean value is zero.

Comment: You're right about the mild bias in the implementation, but wrong about the fact that the expected mean distance from the origin is 0.  In this case, the distance will be about 1/2 * sqrt(pi) * sqrt(N), where N is the number of steps taken.

Comment: @DSM: I don't understand.  If there is no bias-- that is, if N, S, E and W are equally likely outcomes on each random event-- how can the expected value of a large number of events be anything other than zero?  I'm not talking about variance, and I don't think OP is either; I'm talking about mean.

Comment: Your last point isn't correct, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103142/expected-value-of-random-walk

Comment: @CactusWoman: fair point and edited.  I only intended to address expected value, not variance, but I wasn't at all clear.

Comment: The expected distance from the origin for a single random walk is also not zero, as DSM said. The average distance from the origin if you run a large number of *separate* random walks is 0, but for a single random walk the expected distance from the origin is the value that I linked to. But you don't have to take my word for it, you can try it out with an unbiased generator

Comment: [And note, in case it's not clear, that the page CW linked to agrees with my limiting expression above-- gamma(3/2) = sqrt(pi)/2.]

Comment: @CactusWoman/@DSM: Yes, I understand that expected distance from the origin for a single random walk in OP's case is, trivially, 1.  I was not addressing expected distance; only expected position.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the above answers, which are all good and correct, the random generator implemented in Python is the Mersenne Twister one which is known to not pass 2 of the hardest tests of the famous application TestU01 and which is known also to be a little big long to evaluate.
You could rather try this library: PyRandLib. See:

- https://schmouk.github.io/PyRandLib/ to easily download archives versions, and
- https://github.com/schmouk/PyRandLib to get access to code.

This library contains many of the best-in-class pseudo-random numbers generators while acting exactly as does the Python "built-in" library random.
Just un-zip or un-tar the downloaded archive in the 'Lib/site-packages/' sub-directory of your Python directory. And then, enjoy :-)